# Get string[] elements with index of int[] indices

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have a `string[]`, and want to get the elements of the `string[]` that has an index, *of which i know exist*, specified in an `int[]`.

```
string[] stringArray = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" };
int[] indices = { 1, 2, 4, 6 };
```

From this, I am trying to get a `string[]` containing `{ "b", "c", "e", "g" }`. Preferably using a lambda expression. How would I do this?

Comment: You don't have a `IEnumerable<string[]>`, you have a `string[]`

Comment: Actually, I *had* an `IEnumerable<string[]>` ;)

Comment: But the example you gave was clearly of a `string[]`, as are many of the responses you received.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way you can do it is like this.

```
string[] result = indices.Select(i => stringArray[i]).ToArray()
```

Comment: How you are sure `stringArray[i]` is available?

Answer (score 6):

```
indices.Select(i => stringArray[i]);
```

Comment: How you are sure `stringArray[i]` is available?

Comment: I'm not. I have no idea how an IndexOutOfRangeException is to be handled. I leave that to the OP.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri I'd say, that since I am providing the indices, I am implying that I know they exist.

Comment: @sshow, I think you should edit your question, you should say that I have indices in range. your current situation is ambiguous, and I'm not the only person says this.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri I have made an edit to my question to emphasize that I know the indices exist.

Answer (score 3):

```
stringArray.Where((x,index) => indices.Contains(index));
```

Comment: Why would you do it that way rather than, you know, the fast way?

Comment: @Harold, As Adrian mentioned this is safer, you should always know that element[i] is available to use `.Select(i=>element[i])` else you will get an unwanted exception, and question doesn't says that element[i] is always available.

Comment: Well I can't say I agree. Sure the exception disappears, but should you want it to? Asking for an index that doesn't exist is probably a bug somewhere else.

Comment: @harold, Q:I have a string[], and want to get the elements of the string[] that has an index specified in an int[], It doesn't says that throw an exception when specific index is not available, I think my way is closer to current version of question. but again OP should determine which is an answer, but by current Q statement IMO my answer is best (not in performance, but in correction).

Comment: The question just looks poorly phrased to me.. can't hurt to OP to see both ways though I suppose

Comment: @Harold, I'm agree, because of this thought, I used this method (sure is harder than others) and currently seems OP like another answer, and In fact now we can rephrase his question.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach( int i in indices){
    string s = stringArray[i]
    //DO stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**LINQ:**   `var result = from indice in indices select stringArray[indice]` 
**LAMBDA EXPRESSION:**  `var result = indices.Select(i => stringArray[i])`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var result= (
    from str in stringArray.Select ((a,i) =>new {a,i})
    where indices.Contains(str.i)
    select str
);
```